# Add object to related list

Tags: related-list

After googling for one hour I couldn't find any answer to this question. Sorry if this duplicated but I couldn't find it.

I've created a custom object that I want to add opportunities to the related list.
[image]
So I created a lookup relationship linked to opportunity, but I can't add it to the list.

How could I add a new field to related lists?
How could I add my lookup relationship to the related lists?

[image]

I can see the object as amplified lookup, but not in the related list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The section you're in is for Expanded Lookups, which are for mobile devices. You need to be using the Related List section instead ("Listas relacionadas"). In the layout editor, different parts of the page layout will turn green to indicate that you can drop elements in that area. Notice how when you select "Búsquedas ampliadas", the "Tarjetas móviles (Solo Salesforce móvil)" section turns green to indicate you can add items there while dragging.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but I can't find the object opportunities in the related lists. So, maybe the question is how can I create a opportunity lookup that appears in the related lists.

Comment: @RobertoGimenez If you created the lookup field, you would have a related list. The list name will appear as whatever you called it while creating the field.